# Are there any way to filter of{} not put aditional map?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, ngrx, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have pipe and It will return `of{}` when some error occured. So I need to filter it  , to other code flows. Currently I used following senario. I need to know , are there any way to remove map and filter it in the exiting filter ?

```
 readonly k$ = combineLatest(
    [this.x$.pipe(filter(isNotNullOrUndefined), //this filter not filtering  of{} type.
      map((res: A) => {  //need to remove this map
        return res;
      })
    ), this.y$]).pipe(shareReplayUntil(this.destroySub));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return `of(null)` instead of `of({})` so that your filter function `isNotNullOrUndefined` filters the `null` value properly.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean an observable of an empty object `of({})`?

you could check if it's not empty with `Object.keys(res).length !== 0`

`filter((res: A) => isNotNullOrUndefined(res) && Object.keys(res).length !== 0)`